# Оформление оператора __matmul__

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

Как правильно и стильно писать код с [новым](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#pep-465-a-dedicated-infix-operator-for-matrix-multiplication) [оператором](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.matmul) умножения матриц? И почему?

`A@ B` ?

`A@B` ?

`A @ B` ?

В PEP465 использует третий вариант записи, но по мне он слишком длинный. И непривычный. А второй короткий. А первый совсем непонятен. Документация `numpy`, например, вообще не использует символ, заменяя все на `A.matmul(B)`. Странный вообще оператор. Почему PEP8 молчит по этому поводу?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id28) не молчит по этому поводу:

> If operators with different priorities are used, consider adding whitespace around the operators with the lowest priority(ies). Use your own judgment; however, never use more than one space, and always have the same amount of whitespace on both sides of a binary operator.

Исходя из этого, первый вариант недопустим, второй можно использовать в том случае, если в выражении используются операторы с более низким приоритетом, а во всех остальных случаях использовать третий.

Comment: Верно, а я ожидал явного указания.